# React functional components not rendering in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-functional-component

I am using only functional components in React so I can get a better grip on hooks.
But I am having trouble rendering my functional components in the App.js.

Why will only the ‘Login’ component/path render in the browser? None of the others. Please help me discover what is wrong with my App.js. Thank you!

**App.js** *(I have commented out the hook/removed the prop, to simplify it)*

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Signup from './components/Signup';
console.log('app loading')
function App() {
  // const [user, setUser] = useState(props.user)
  // console.log(props.user)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    {/* <h1>This is app.js</h1> */}
    <Route
        exact path = "/"
        compotent={Home}
      /> 
    <Route
        exact path="/login" 
        component={Login}
    />
    <Route
        exact path = "/signup"
        compotent={Signup}
      /> 
    </div>
    
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'
console.log('home loading')
export default function Home() {
  console.log('home function')
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>This is home.js</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Login.js** *(this is the only one that renders)*

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
console.log('login loading')
export default function Login() {
  console.log('login function loading')
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>Login.js</h1>
    <Link to="/auth/google">Login With Google</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Signup.js**

```
import React from 'react'
export default function Signup() {
  console.log('signup function loading')
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>This is Signup.js</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a spelling mistake in the '/' and '/signup' routes.

I had written `'compo*t*ent=...'` instead of `'compo**n**ent'`.

The code is now corrected and the `compo**n**ents` are rendering just find.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove spaces `exact path = "/" => exact path="/"` for both Home and Signup routes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Signup from './components/Signup';
console.log('app loading')
function App() {
  // const [user, setUser] = useState(props.user)
  // console.log(props.user)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    {/* <h1>This is app.js</h1> */}
    <Router>
      <Route
        exact path = "/"
        compotent={Home}
      /> 
      <Route
          exact path="/login" 
          component={Login}
      />
      <Route
          exact path = "/signup"
          compotent={Signup}
        /> 
    </Router>
    
    </div>
    
  );
}
export default App;
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Please restructure your **app.jsx** with the below changes:

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'; //I MADE CHANGE HERE
import Home from './components/Home'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Signup from './components/Signup';

function App() {
  console.log('app loading')
  return (
    <div className="App">
  <Router>     //I MADE CHANGE HERE
    <Route
        exact path = "/"
        compotent={Home}
      /> 
    <Route
        exact path="/login" 
        component={Login}
    />
    <Route
        exact path = "/signup"
        compotent={Signup}
      /> 
 </Router> //I MADE CHANGE HERE
    </div>
    
  );
}
export default App;
```